# I am looking to eliminate observations if they are not within a certain date range from a neighboring column

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a dataset that has two date columns.  The first is the date a test was performed (Date 1).  The second column is the date an additional test (Date 2) was performed.  I want to eliminate observations if Date 2 is not within plus or minus 3 days of Date 1.

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
Date1 <- c("2016-07-01", "2016-07-02", "2016-07-03","2017-08-01")
Date2 <- c("2016-07-02", "2016-07-03", "2016-07-04","2017-08-15")

df = data.frame(ID, Date1, Date2)




ID       Date1                Date2    
1   2016-07-01           2016-07-02     
2   2016-07-02           2016-07-03     
3   2016-07-03           2016-07-04     
4   2017-08-01           2017-08-15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do something like this

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Date")), ymd) %>%
    filter(Date2 <= Date1 %m+% days(3) & Date2 >= Date1 %m-% days(3))
#  ID      Date1      Date2
#1  1 2016-07-01 2016-07-02
#2  2 2016-07-02 2016-07-03
#3  3 2016-07-03 2016-07-04
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Doing with `abs`

```
df[abs(as.Date(df$Date1)-as.Date(df$Date2))<3,]
  ID      Date1      Date2
1  1 2016-07-01 2016-07-02
2  2 2016-07-02 2016-07-03
3  3 2016-07-03 2016-07-04
```